# Mysql auto insert record in primary table if not exist

Tags: mysql, trigger, foreign-key, primary-key

Is it possible to auto insert a record into the primary table if the record does not exist when adding a foreign key?

For example, assume these tables:
 - user(id, name, age)
 - topic(id, name)
 - post(userId, topicId, text, createdAt, updatedAt)

Now i am pulling posts from some source and saving the records in the `post` table. But sometimes the data that is being returned contains a `userId` or a `topicId` that is not yet in my database. So everytime i would have to check if the `user` and `topic` records exist then save if not. Only then my `post` record would be valid and saved.

I want to be able to save the `post` even if its related `user` or `topic` does not exist, and add an empty row with the in these tables having the ids that have been stored in the `post` table.

Example:

Current User Table

```
+----+------+-----+
| id | name | age |
+----+------+-----+
| 15 | Paul | 26  |
+----+------+-----+
| 56 | John | 31  |
+----+------+-----+
```

current Topic Table

```
+----+----------+
| id | name     |
+----+----------+
| 5  | Business |
+----+----------+
| 12 | General  |
+----+----------+
```

current Post Table:

```
+--------+---------+----------------+-------------+-------------+
| userId | topicId | text           | createdAt   | updatedAt   |
+--------+---------+----------------+-------------+-------------+
| 15     | 12      | blah blah blah | *timestamp* | *timestamp* |
+--------+---------+----------------+-------------+-------------+
| 56     | 5       | lorem ipsum... | *timestamp* | *timestamp* |
+--------+---------+----------------+-------------+-------------+
```

So then i fetch post from some sources an get a new 1 `This is a new topic` posted by a user with id 72 in a topic with id 2. The source only returns the id, and to obtain the rest of the details of the user, i should make another request to their api.

Post Table after:

```
+--------+---------+---------------------+-------------+-------------+
| userId | topicId | text                | createdAt   | updatedAt   |
+--------+---------+---------------------+-------------+-------------+
| 15     | 12      | blah blah blah      | *timestamp* | *timestamp* |
+--------+---------+---------------------+-------------+-------------+
| 56     | 5       | lorem ipsum...      | *timestamp* | *timestamp* |
+--------+---------+---------------------+-------------+-------------+
| 72     | 2       | This is a new topic | *timestamp* | *timestamp* |
+--------+---------+---------------------+-------------+-------------+
```

User Table After:

```
+----+------+-----+
| id | name | age |
+----+------+-----+
| 15 | Paul | 26  |
+----+------+-----+
| 56 | John | 31  |
+----+------+-----+
| 72 |      |     |
+----+------+-----+
```

Topic Table after

```
+----+------------+
| id | name       |
+----+------------+
| 2  |            |
+----+------------+
| 5  | Business   |
+----+------------+
| 12 | General    |
+----+------------+
```

So now that i have this, i can make my request to their api and look for data for user with id 72 and data for topic with id 2.

Comment: When posting table structures ( for MySQL - your server may vary), could you please use SHOW CREATE TABLE My_Table\G. That way they can be easily copied and pasted, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get it automated via `FOREIGN KEY`.

Plan A:  Use a `TRIGGER`.

Plan B:  Use `INSERT .. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ..`.